# Desktop Bridge UWP - Submission

Tags: vb.net, uwp, windows-store-apps, submission, capability

On the submission properties tab on my UWP application, I cannot select "No" for the "Does this product access, collect, or transmit personal information (data that could be used to identify a person)?" question.

It is saying "Based on the capabilities your submission declares, a privacy policy URL is required."

I have reviewed my capabilities (which is empty), and I am not using any personal information on my application.

Comment: Is the capabilities section actually completely empty or is the internet client capability on? This is set by default for UWP apps and is enough to trigger the privacy policy requirement.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes It is on as the application reads data from the web page, see below part from app manifest ->   <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>

Comment: Then that would be the reason. I have posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `internetCapability` is enabled, you will be required to provide a privacy policy, as your app could theoretically send any personal data over the internet.

You can easily generate a privacy policy with a tool like [this](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com).

Comment: Updated answer with privacy policy generator

Comment: So what happens if i un-checked it, as i am not getting any data from the user, its just for parsing a webpage ( sorry for the novice level question in advance)

Comment: Then you need to have it checked as the app would then not be allowed to access the web page by the system at all

Comment: But providing the policy is easy, just mention you are not transfering user data in any way and it will be OK

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and really useful reply

Comment: I have created the html privacy policy file as you posted but how can i add it to my submission as i don't have any webpage to assign it?

Comment: You need to host it somewhere. You can just create a free hosting or put it in a public filesharing

Answer (score 1):

Although @Martin's response is technically correct, it's incomplete.

Because you are submitting a Desktop Bridge app (with `runFullTrust` capability) your app has access to essentially everything the user has access to, and thus `internetClient` is redundant (unless you also have UWP components like a background task). According to the Store product page, your app has access to "all system resources" so in your privacy policy you might want to mention more than just network usage - you could mention that you don't collect or use any personal data, won't read files or access the microphone or the camera or location etc. I don't believe that's required, but it might make customers feel better.

(Note that the Store text might change to something more descriptive in the future).